# Find a table row by ID and edit its cells?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to edit values in a table where the rows/cells are generated dynamically by Bootgrid so they have no html id. I am currently doing this by going to tr:nth-child, but this only works if the value I set for rowID corresponds to that position in the table.

Ex: If I remove the 3rd item from the table, the item with rowID=4 is now the 3rd child of the tr, and the following code will edit the wrong cells.

I need to be able to find the correct row to edit by ID, not position in the grid. I posted a similar question yesterday, but I have improved this to better clarify what I am trying to do.

```js
// I get the rowID by clicking an Edit button on the table row, like this:
rowID = $(this).data("row-id");

// This is what I'm doing now to edit the table:
$('#or-table tr:nth-child(' + rowID + ') td:nth-child(3)').html($('#aff-selector').val());
$('#or-table tr:nth-child(' + rowID + ') td:nth-child(4)').html($('#editor-code').val());
$('#or-table tr:nth-child(' + rowID + ') td:nth-child(5)').html($('#editor-lat').val());
$('#or-table tr:nth-child(' + rowID + ') td:nth-child(6)').html($('#editor-long').val());
```

```html
<!-- This is the table: -->

<table id="or-table" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped bootgrid-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
         <th data-column-id="id" data-identifier="true" data-type="numeric">ID</th>
         <th data-column-id="aff" align="center">Affiliation</th>
         <th data-column-id="code">Symbol Code</th>
         <th data-column-id="lat">Latitude</th>
         <th data-column-id="long">Longitude</th>
         <th data-column-id="commands" data-formatter="commands" data-sortable="false">Commands</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <!-- These tr/td generated by Bootgrid: -->
      <tr data-row-id="1">
        <td class="select-cell" style="{{ctx.style}}">
        <td class="text-left" style="">1</td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">H</td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">SHG-EVAI-------</td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">35.39135902572556</td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">-116.52048110961914</td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
      </tr>
      <tr data-row-id="2">
        <td class="select-cell" style="{{ctx.style}}">
        <td class="text-left" style="">2</td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">H</td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">SHG-EVAT-------</td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">35.40241360341436</td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">-116.52648925781249</td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
      </tr>      
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: how are you initiating this? is it a button click? are you clicking on the row? I think this could be made much easier if you provide more detail

Comment: It is initiated by clicking an Edit button on the table row.

Comment: so you can use `$(this).parent()` which will give you the parent of the clicked on button (which could/should be the the `tr`). can you show me where the edit button is in the html and how it looks?

Comment: look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadabdul3/t67ksynu/6/ if it solves your problem I can add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the following selector

`$("#or-table tr[data-row-id='2']")`

to select the relevant `tr` element.

Obviously you should change the `2` value depending on what you want to achieve :)

Answer (score 1):

This is way too complicated in your code. ;)

```
// you have the row already? Use it!
var columns = $('td', this);

// 'eq()' gives you the column by index
columns.eq(3).html($('#aff-selector').val());
columns.eq(4).html($('#editor-code').val());
columns.eq(5).html($('#editor-lat').val());
columns.eq(6).html($('#editor-long').val());
```

Or if you want to select over the `rowID`:

```
var columns = $('tr[data-row-id=' + rowID + '] td');

columns.eq(3).html($('#aff-selector').val());
columns.eq(4).html($('#editor-code').val());
columns.eq(5).html($('#editor-lat').val());
columns.eq(6).html($('#editor-long').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/fsbwhhu4/

```
function find_in_table(table, column, row) {
    var table = $(table)
    var column_index = table.find('thead tr [data-column-id=' + column + ']').index()
    var row = table.find('tr[data-row-id="' + row + '"]')

    return row.find('td').eq(column_index)
}

// Usage:
find_in_table('#or-table', 'lat', 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the **Id** within any cell, then the below should work

```
 document.getElementById("myID "+tempIdx).parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
```

provided table is in the below format

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <p id="myID 1" />
    </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<td></td>
<td>
    <p id="myID 2" />
</td>
</tr>
<td>
    <p id="myID 3" />
</td>
</tr>
```